# Check if a string contains only letters, digits and underscores

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

I have to check if a string contains only letters, digits and underscores.
This is how I tried but it doesn't work:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=snameA.Length-1; i++)
{
    validA = validA && (char.IsLetterOrDigit(snameA[i])||snameA[i].Equals("_"));
}
```

Comment: try using Regex for this that checks over this pattern: ([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)

Comment: I don't know. validA is a boolean which must be set on true only if the conditions are accomplished but it is set on true even if the string has special characters

Comment: What does "doesn't work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: Note: code was altered in the meantime.

Comment: I added "validA &&" but it still doesn't worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I love Linq for this kind of question:

```
bool validA = sname.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c.Equals('_'));
```

Answer (score 10):

You are assigning `validA` every time again, without checking its previous value. Now you always get the value of the last check executed.

You could 'and' the result:

```
validA &= (char.IsLetterOrDigit(snameA[i]) || snameA[i] == '_');
```

This would mean you still run all characters, which might be useless if the first check failed. So it is better to simply step out if it fails:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=snameA.Length-1; i++)
{
    validA = (char.IsLetterOrDigit(snameA[i]) || snameA[i] == '_');

    if (!validA)
    { break; } // <-- see here
}
```

Or with LINQ:

```
validA = snameA.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_');
```

Comment: I have retracted my downvote. Using regexp is a matter of choice I guess and your answer is completely correct too.

Comment: Thanks. I don't say OP shouldn't use regex, but now he knows what was wrong with his code. :) Thanks for your honesty.

Answer (score 5):

you can use regex

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$");

if(regex1.IsMatch(snameA))
{

}
```

Comment: `Regex` taking it's own instance as a parameter!

Comment: btw, `a-zA-Z0-9_` is the same as `\w`

Comment: @Thomas: no, there's a subtle difference: `a-zA-Z0-9_` accepts *English* alphabet only, when  `\w` accepts *any* letters, e.g. `Переменная` (Variable in Russian). You're quite right: the current inplementation in the question (via `char.IsLetterOrDigit`) corresponds `\w*` in regular expression

Answer (score 3):

I would use a Regex

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

// Compare a string against the regular expression
return regex.IsMatch(stringToTest);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try matching a regular expression. There is a built in type for "letters, digits and underscores", which is "\w".

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\w*");
rgs.IsMatch(yourString);
```

If you require 1 or more, then use "\w+".

Further information here: [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *if a string contains **only** letters, digits and underscores* => Yours check if the string contains *any* letters, digits and underscores

Answer (score 1):

First, *letter* is a bit vague term: do you mean `a..z` and `A..Z` characters or letter could belong to *any alphabet*, e.g. `а..я` and `А..Я` (Russian, Cyrillic letters). According to your *current implementation*, you want the *second option*.

Typical solution with loop is to check until first counter example:

```
  Boolean validA = true; // true - no counter examples so far

  // Why for? foreach is much readble here
  foreach(Char ch in sname) 
    // "!= '_'" is more readable than "Equals"; and wants no boxing
    if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) && ! (ch != '_')) { 
      Boolean validA = false; // counter example (i.e. non-letter/digit symbol found)

      break; // <- do not forget this: there's no use to check other characters
    }
```

However you can simplify the code with either *Linq*:

```
  validA = sname.All(ch => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) || ch == '_');
```

Or *regular expression*:

```
  validA = Regex.IsMatch(sname, @"^\w*$");
```